# Удаление строки таблицы динамически созданной строки и кнопки

Tags: javascript

друзья и коллеги!
Имеется таблица, по клику формируется другая. С кнопкой на конце. Как на данную кнопку повесить событие с функцией удаления данной строки?

Спасибо!

```js
let table = document.getElementById('tables');
let table2 = document.getElementById('tables2');
let table3 = document.getElementById('tables3');
tableCreate(table, table2); // Вызов функции, первая таблица - которая прослушиатся, вторая - заполняется
tableCreate(table2, table3);

function tableCreate(tableParrent, tableChild) {
    tableParrent.addEventListener('click', function (e) { // Добавляем прослушиватель
        let target = e.target; // Получаем объект по которому кликнули
        //console.log(target.tagName);

        if (target.tagName != 'BUTTON') {
            let targetParrent = target.parentNode; // Получаем родителя объекта клика
            let trElem = document.createElement('tr'); // создаем строку таблицы
            tableChild.append(trElem); // Добавляем строку в целевую таблицу
            // Вывод ячеек в строку таблицы
            for (let index = 0; index < targetParrent.cells.length; index++) {
                let tdElem = document.createElement('td');
                tdElem.innerHTML = targetParrent.cells[index].innerHTML;
                trElem.append(tdElem);
            }
            let tdElemButton = document.createElement('td');
            let buttonElem = document.createElement('button');
            buttonElem.classList.add('buttonElemClass');
            //buttonElem.value = 'Удалить';
            buttonElem.innerHTML = 'Удалить!';
            buttonElem.click = "deleteRow";
            trElem.append(tdElemButton);
            tdElemButton.append(buttonElem);
        }
        // Настройка прослушивателя на кнопку
        
        // КОНЕЦ прослушивателя кнопки
    });
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: aquamarine;
}

#tables {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#tables td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px;
}

#tables2 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: burlywood;
}

#tables2 td {
    border: 1px solid black ;
    padding: 3px;
}

#tables3 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: gold;

}

#tables3 td {
    border: 1px solid black ;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <table id="tables">
        <caption>Таблица №1</caption>
        <tr class="">
            <td>1</td>
            <td id="piece">19011245</td>
            <td>22ГЮ</td>
            <td>Нет примечаний</td>
            <td>Произведено</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>19011246</td>
            <td>09Г2С</td>
            <td>Есть дефект</td>
            <td>В производстве</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>19011247</td>
            <td>09Г2С</td>
            <td>Необходимо перевести в брак</td>
            <td>Задержана</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table id='tables2'>
        <caption>Таблица №2</caption>
    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table id='tables3'>
        <caption>Таблица №3</caption>
    </table>
    <script src="js.js"></script>   
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let table = document.getElementById('tables');
let table2 = document.getElementById('tables2');
let table3 = document.getElementById('tables3');
tableCreate(table, table2); // Вызов функции, первая таблица - которая прослушиатся, вторая - заполняется
tableCreate(table2, table3);

function tableCreate(tableParrent, tableChild) {
  tableParrent.addEventListener('click', function(e) { // Добавляем прослушиватель
    let target = e.target; // Получаем объект по которому кликнули
    //console.log(target.tagName);

    if (target.tagName != 'BUTTON') {
      let targetParrent = target.parentNode; // Получаем родителя объекта клика
      let trElem = document.createElement('tr'); // создаем строку таблицы
      tableChild.append(trElem); // Добавляем строку в целевую таблицу
      // Вывод ячеек в строку таблицы
      for (let index = 0; index < targetParrent.cells.length; index++) {
        let tdElem = document.createElement('td');
        tdElem.innerHTML = targetParrent.cells[index].innerHTML;
        trElem.append(tdElem);
      }
      let tdElemButton = document.createElement('td');
      let buttonElem = document.createElement('button');
      buttonElem.classList.add('buttonElemClass');
      //buttonElem.value = 'Удалить';
      buttonElem.innerHTML = 'Удалить!';
      buttonElem.click = "deleteRow";

      buttonElem.addEventListener('click', deleteRow); // <--------

      trElem.append(tdElemButton);
      tdElemButton.append(buttonElem);
    }
    // Настройка прослушивателя на кнопку

    // КОНЕЦ прослушивателя кнопки
  });
}

function deleteRow(e) { // <--------
  e.target.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
}
```